# Is the shapechanger trait of a weretiger a class feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

Is the shapechanger trait of a [weretiger](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Weretiger#content) a class feature?

This would be a useful information if the creature is target of magic jar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Shapechange is not a class feature.

The only special trait for monsters that is also a class feature is Spellcasting since it is specifically called that in the Introduction to the Monster Manual (***emphasis*** mine):

> **Spellcasting**
>
> A monster with the Spellcasting ***class feature*** has a spellcaster level and spell slots